# Lagrange multipliers and mle

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, lagrange-multipliers

[image]

Could someone give a method that works for the following question? I am new to the topic and cannot understand why there is no constant $\lambda$ in the first two equations (which would arise from the Lagrange multiplier method). I assumed it uses the equation  $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}[l(\mathbf{x}\mid\theta) + \lambda(p+q+r-1)] = 0$ to get $\lambda$ in terms of the unknown probabilities, but this doesn't seem to give the required answer once $\lambda$ is fed back into the other equations.

My likelihood function was
$$\frac{n}{x_1!x_2!x_3!x_4!}(p^2+2pr)^{x_1}(q^2+2qr)^{x_2}(2pq)^{x_3}r^{2x_4}$$
which lead to 
$$\frac{2x_1(\dot{p}+\dot{r})}{\dot{p}^2+2\dot{p}\dot{r}}+\frac{x_3}{\dot{p}}+\lambda=0$$
$$\frac{2x_2(\dot{q}+\dot{r})}{\dot{q}^2+2\dot{q}\dot{r}}+\frac{x_3}{\dot{q}}+\lambda=0$$
$$\frac{2x_1\dot{p}}{\dot{p}^2+2\dot{p}\dot{r}}+\frac{2x_2\dot{q}}{\dot{q}^2+2\dot{q}\dot{r}}+\frac{2x_4}{\dot{r}}+\lambda=0$$
$$\dot{p}+\dot{q}+\dot{r}=1$$
So where am I going wrong?

Comment: consider adding the `self-study` tag: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: You should at least show us your formulation of the likelihood and of the maximum likelihood estimation (presumably, constrained, p + q + r = 1) optimization problem. Otherwise readers have no idea what any of this is even about.  Then show us your attempt, even if incomplete, to state the optimality conditions, including use of Lagrange multiplier. Then see whether you can eliminate the Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: I've updated it

Comment: Compare your first, second, and fourth equations to those in the question, using the given values of the $x_i.$  You will find remarkable similarities: some differences are places where you made minor errors.  Once you fix those, you should be on the right track.

Comment: I have done this, but I cannot see how to eliminate lambda!

Comment: Check your second one again. Also your $\lambda$s should be negative no?

Comment: Whether they are all positive or negative shouldn't matter. I still can't figure out how to eliminate lambda to get the required answer.